# How to insert a dictionary to a sqlite database?

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm trying to write a dictionary into sql database, but without success giving me:

```
Error binding parameter 3 - probably unsupported type.
```

data structure:

```
{
"url": "https://www.wellness.com/dir/6022571/acupuncturist/ri/east-greenwich/hwasook-lee-phoenix- 
fertility-center-dac",
"First_and_Last_Name": "Hwasook Lee, D.Ac.",
"About": "Phoenix Fertility Center specializes in the treatment of infertility, hormonal imbalances, 
women's health and pregnancy related conditions. Our passion revolves around empowering you to 
understand how your body works and how your everyday habits like eating and sleeping have a direct 
impact on your health. ",
"Services": [
"When I entered acupuncture school, I knew that I wanted to specialize in women's health and 
gynecology. ", "One of my mandates as an acupuncturist is to empower my...", "Fertility"
]}
```

code:

```
db = sqlite3.connect('wellness.db')

    db.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS wellness(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                                                   url TEXT, First_and_Last_Name TEXT, 
                                                   About TEXT, Services TEXT);''') 
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO wellness(url, First_and_Last_Name, About, Services) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)', 
                  (item['url'], item['First_and_Last_Name'], item['About'], item['Services']))

    db.commit()
    db.close()
```

Comment: `item['Services']` looks like a list of strings, not a string. How do you intend that to be inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The

`item['Services']`

it contains a list and not a **string**

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO wellness(url, First_and_Last_Name, About, Services) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)', 
                  (item['url'], item['First_and_Last_Name'], item['About'], '-'.join(item['Services'])  ))
```

try to use join in order for them to make a full string since the item['Services'] is a list